# Abrir o ejecutar una aplicación WinForms o de Escritorio desde MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-forms

Cordial saludo, por favor me orientan como abrir o ejecutar una aplicación Windows Form o de Escritorio desde MVC. lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario final haga clic a un botón de la aplicación Web se abra la aplicación de escritorio que ya he hecho para tal fin.

Lo que busco es un escenario tipo UTorrent donde un vinculo pide autorización para abrir la aplicación de escritorio y se tiene de igual forma control de la aplicación de escritorio (desarrollada por mi) y de la ruta de ubicación del mismo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días Jorge.

Por razones de seguridad la ejecución de aplicaciones desde los navegadores web está limitada. Imaginemos que al entrar a un sitio web se ejecute automáticamente una aplicación en tu ordenador. Podría traer problemas muy grandes. En Internet Explorer permite ejecutar una aplicación advirtiendo, de antemano, los riesgos que esto conlleva (ver solución 4).

Entonces las soluciones que veo posibles para lograr el objetivo que planteás son:

1 - Tomar desde el assembly (la aplicación WinForms) las funcionalidades como si fuera una librería (DLL) y presentarlas mediante la interfaz web.

2 - Una alternativa muy conveniente sería presentar esas funcionalidades como servicios web, lo cual te daría una arquitectura de software fácilmente ampliable. Por ejemplo, podrías, luego, consumir esos servicios web desde una aplicación para móviles.

3 - Dejar un link de descarga de la aplicación WinForms y que el usuario sea quien la descargue y luego la ejecute (generalmente los navegadores dan la posibilidad de ejecutar al finalizar la descarga). Esto, además, te libraría de la necesidad de conocer la ubicación de la aplicación en la PC de cada usuario.

4 - Si conocés la ruta de la aplicación y la aplicación web MVC se accede mediante Internet Explorer podrías utilizar este código (podés encontrar ejemplos como este si buscás algo así como "ejecutar aplicación desde Javascript" o en inglés: "open executable file from javascript"):

```html
<html> 
 <head> 
     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  objetoActiveX = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
  function EjecutarPrograma()   
         {
   var Ruta = "file:///E:/Prueba.exe";
   objetoActiveX.Run(Ruta);
   }   
    </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <h1>Ejecutar programa</h1> 
    <p>Funcional en Internet Explorer</p>
    <button onclick="EjecutarPrograma()">Ejecutar</button> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

5 - Otra alternativa consiste en "declarar un protocolo mediante el registro de Windows" en cada PC para que cuando la aplicación web intente hacer una llamada a ese protocolo sepa qué acción tomar. Dejo un ejemplo. Podés encontrar info en https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Primero, generamos un HTML de prueba para ver qué resultado debería generar la aplicación web MVC:

```html
<html> 
 <head> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <h1>Ejecutar programa</h1>
 <p><a href="EjecutarApp:Probando">Por protocolo con parámetros</a></p> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

En segundo lugar, vamos a generar una aplicación en C# de tipo WinForms con dos botones y algo más de código en el método Main y en el manejador del evento Load() del formulario principal. El botón 1 es el que registrará el protocolo en el registro de Windows y el botón 2 eliminará por completo las claves generadas. Quizás podrías registrar el protocolo en un instalador y quitar el registro si el usuario desinstala la aplicación de Escritorio.

Entonces, creamos la aplicación WinForms (en nuestro ejemplo se llama PruebaEjecutarApp), agregamos dos botones. Al primero lo llamamos Registrar. Le hacemos doble click y el método manejador del evento click del "button1" nos debería quedar así:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey clave = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            clave.CreateSubKey("EjecutarApp");
            clave = clave.OpenSubKey("EjecutarApp", true);
            clave.SetValue("", "Protocolo de EjecutarApp");
            clave.SetValue("URL Protocol", "");
            clave.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon");

            RegistryKey clave2 = clave.OpenSubKey("DefaultIcon", true);
            clave2.SetValue("", "PruebaEjecutarApp.exe,1");

            clave.CreateSubKey("shell");
            clave = clave.OpenSubKey("shell", true);
            clave.CreateSubKey("open");
            clave = clave.OpenSubKey("open", true);
            clave.CreateSubKey("command");
            clave = clave.OpenSubKey("command", true);
            clave.SetValue("", @"""E:\PruebaEjecutarApp\PruebaEjecutarApp\bin\Debug\PruebaEjecutarApp.exe"" ""%1""");

            clave.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Luego, al segundo botón los llamamos "Quitar registro" y le hacemos doble click. El método nos debería quedar así:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey clave = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            clave.DeleteSubKeyTree("EjecutarApp");
            clave.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

En la ventana principal de la aplicación le hacemos doble click al título y el método nos debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Argumentos.Length!=0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Recibido: " + Argumentos[0]);
        }
    }
```

Por útlimo, en el Program.cs dejamos el método Main de la siguiente manera:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 nuevo = new Form1();
        nuevo.Argumentos = args;
        Application.Run(nuevo);
    }
```

Al abrir el HTML y hacer click en el link se mostrará una caja de texto con la leyenda "Recibido: EjecutarApp:Probando". En cambio, si abrimos la aplicación con doble click no se mostrará esa caja de texto.

Espero haberte ayudado!
Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu información, lo que busco es un escenario tipo UTorrent donde un vinculo pide autorización para abrir la aplicación de escritorio y se tiene de igual forma control de la aplicacion de escritorio y de la ruta de ubicacion del mismo.  Gracias

Comment: Bien. En ese caso creo que la alternativa número 5 puede ser la adecuada, dado que podrías enviar como parámetros a la aplicación los valores que desees desde la aplicación web y hacer que la de escritorio los interprete (como hace el uTorrent con las direcciones correspondientes al torrent). Quizás con un instalador podrías registrar el protocolo que le permita al programa interpretar esto. Si querés un ejemplo podemos ver de armarlo. Saludos!

Comment: Ignacio, gracias por tu respuesta, te agradecería mucho un ejemplo

Comment: Dale! Ni bien tenga un ratito te lo armo. Quizás en el fin de semana te lo subo acá mismo!